# Importing a mysql database into an existing rails project

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, console

I'm following this rails tutorial and something went wrong with the db but hopefully they provide the db sample for the chapter. I just want to import the sample db. I'm using console. Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the right way but I just deleted the database and migrations and run `rake db:migrate` and it worked.